# Software to test disk drives, via PXE boot?

Tags: testing, pxe-boot

Is there any software out there which will allow a disk drive to be tested, which boots via PXE?

I have a fully functional PXE environment which allows memtesting, installation, and drive nuking - but to test a disk I have to boot into an NFS-root system, and run badblocks/fsck.  Neither of those solutions are terribly good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with badblocks?

If you are up for purchasing a site-license for it there are a few articles out there where people have netbooted [spinrite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm).  It boots fine via memdisk.

Most manufacture HD diagnostic tools can also be booted via memdisk.  Download from seagate/wd/whatever.

Comment: Nothing is horribly wrong with badblocks, but specifically netbooting a tester would be useful given my automated environment.  As for device-specific testing that is a great idea, but I do have a few hundred servers with various drives - so even if the testing isn't 100% it would be nicer to avoid that route.